# java jfilechooser to list only "hello*.txt files" and no directory changing

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, filechooser

I am trying to use JFileChooser to select files with this name format: **LS48*.drv**. 
at the same time I want to limit the user to look into only a specific directory say **c:\data**. So I don't want the user to be able to change directories or to other drive names. 
Base of my code segment below can you please provide me some hints:

```
 m_fileChooser = new JFileChooser("c:\\data"); // looking for LS48*.drv files
  m_fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("drivers(*.drv, *.DRV)", "drv", "DRV"));
```

Comment: I got this tip from @Boro to use this code for restricting user to look into specific directory only: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/single-root-file-chooser/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to implement a `FileFilter` subclass of your own, and set this to the file chooser instead of a `FileNameExtensionFilter` instance.

And your `accept` method in this subclass will be something like the following:

```
private static final Pattern LSDRV_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("LS48.*\\.drv");
public boolean accept(File f) {
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        return false;
    }

    return LSDRV_PATTERN.matcher().matches(f.getName());

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you check out this question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041575/using-all-jcombobox-jtextfield-jfilechooser-as-table-editor-overrides-the-re

Answer (score 4):

To prevent directory changes use this:

```
File root = new File("c:\\data");
FileSystemView fsv = new SingleRootFileSystemView( root );
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(fsv);
```

Check this: http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/single-root-file-chooser/

As for the file name pattern, you could use java regular expressions.

Comment: Is this the class you are referring to http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/28/single-root-file-chooser/  If so please edit it into your code.

Comment: Thanks I just added via a coment. Also I was wondering if you can check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041575/using-all-jcombobox-jtextfield-jfilechooser-as-table-editor-overrides-the-re